# Apply folder permissions to folder contents with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I'm applying "Read" permissions to a folder for a certain user. I want them to be able to read notepad files inside.

```
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Test"
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("MyUser","Read","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\Test" $Acl
```

My code properly applies the read permissions to the folder (I can manually check the "Security tab to see this), but does not grant access to the files inside. Access is denied when "MyUser" tries to open a notepad file.

Comment: Do you see the new permissions on the folder when you view the properties? How did the txt file or whatever get into that folder in the first place? Is that file set to inherit permissions (like with a copy) or no (like with a move)?

Comment: Yes, I see the new permissions. I created the txt file for test purposes. I think that may kind of answer my question. It's not a matter of the folder's properties, but the stuff inside, and how that stuff gets its permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use another [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147785(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can set InheritanceFlags for containers and leaf objects. Try:

```
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("MyUser","Read","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
```

Comment: Interesting. Does that just set the stage for future folder contents, or does it also apply to files currently in the folder?

Comment: That depends on the file's permissions. NTFS has inheritance enabled by default, so as long as you don't disable it on a file/folder it will propagate.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks!